# How can I use messengers for crypto transactions?

Tags: cryptography, encryption

Is it possible to use Signal or Telegram for crypto transactions? 
I heard CryptoCat messenger is for such needs, but interested in using those two mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate transaction details to your counterparty using the app, but afaik neither of the messenger apps you mentioned have a cryptocurrency transfer system built into them.

So you'll need a wallet app, but otherwise you can communicate with your counterparty through the messenger app (agree on the amount to be transacted, send a payment address, etc)

Answer (score 0):

For Telegram, there are bots that help do transactions and other crypto-related actions: https://news.bitcoin.com/six-of-the-best-telegram-cryptocurrency-bots/

However, I'd be cautious with these since not all bots are made by good people and I'd check up on them before trusting a bot with any transactional info.

For Signal, there are no options for now but the app's founder is very enthusiastic about crypto: https://bitcoinist.com/the-signal-founder-has-a-plan-to-fix-cryptocurrency/
https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/24/mobilecoin-moxie-marlinspike-binance-labs/

With enough time, they'll likely either to their own venture into the industry or add crypto transaction support in the app.